# How to properly iterate over option class elements?

Tags: javascript

Suppose there are three option html classes:

- options: `option1`, `option2` and `option3`.

Would be great to iterate `document.querySelector()` over each option,
something like:

```
while option in options:
    document.querySelector(option)
 else:
    break


console.log("just executed all the html class options")
```

What is the best way to iterate over a single instruction (`document.querySelector()`)?

Comment: Are you looking for `for(let elem of document.querySelectorAll(<something>))`? Where something depends on what the actual elements look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to get all option classes then do for each over all of them

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');

// now you can use foreach or map or any loop method

options.forEach(option => {
// code
})
```

Comment: Hey @Moufeed Juboqji thanks for the answer, in this case is it necessary to add `;` at the end of the first line?

Comment: it's better if you close the line.